# Multiple linear regression models for a nested dataframe/tibble

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, tibble

I am trying to run multiple linear regressions on a nested dataframe.
I have this data sample:

```
            data.frame(Subcat,Date, COMM1, COMM2,UOM, AUC_TYPE, WINNING_PRICE
                        #--|----------|-----|-----|----|---------|-------|
                        1, 2017-03-07, 40750,41400,"MT","English",35000
                        1, 2017-03-15, 40750,40000,"MT","English",35600

                        2, 2017-10-16, 41000,40500,"METER","Yankee",56440
                        2, 2017-11-06, 41010,40510,"METER","Yankee",52000
                        2, 2019-01-26, 50010,50510,"METER","English",50000

                        3, 2017-03-07, 40750,41400,"MT","English",56900
                        3, 2018-05-26, 50010,50510,"MT","English",47000
                        3, 2019-01-21, 40750,40200,"MT","English",56000
                        3, 2019-01-21, 40750,40200,"MT","English",55900

                        4, 2017-11-08, 37500,39000,"LTR","Dynamic Sealbid",67000
                        4, 2017-11-08, 37500,39000,"LTR","Dynamic Sealbid",65900)
```

Factors/Character variables have been converted to dummy and then nesting on the basis of subcategory is done.

```
                    df2= df[,-2] %>% group_by(Subcat)%>%  nest()
```

The output is a nested dataframe with subcat and data columns.
I am trying to run a regression model for predicting the Winning Price per subcategory using the following code:

```
   df2= df[,-2] %>%  group_by(Subcat)%>%  nest() %>%  
      mutate(fit=map(data, ~ lm(WINNING_PRICE~.,data = .)),
         results=map(fit,augment)) %>%
  unnest()
```

An error output is displayed Error: Input must be list of vectors
In addition: Warning message:
`cols` is now required.
Please use `cols = c(data, fit, results)`. Moreover the dataframe df2 is not being displayed in the console.

I have referred this query '[Running multiple simple linear regressions from a nested dataframe/tibble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49121135/running-multiple-simple-linear-regressions-from-a-nested-dataframe-tibble)'

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to model WINNING_Price ~ Subcat I don't think we have to nest (first example). If need to nest and fit a model in the 'data' column both model elements should be in the nested dataframe WINNING_PRICE ~ COMM1 for example. Here are two examples for each of the scenarios: Also the unnest() error comes from a change to specify the columns you want to unnest with a 'cols = ' argument.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tribble(~Subcat, ~Date, ~COMM1, ~COMM2, ~UOM, ~AUC_TYPE, ~WINNING_PRICE,
                #--|----------|-----|-----|----|---------|-------|
                1, 2017-03-07, 40750,41400,"MT","English",35000,
                1, 2017-03-15, 40750,40000,"MT","English",35600,

                2, 2017-10-16, 41000,40500,"METER","Yankee",56440,
                2, 2017-11-06, 41010,40510,"METER","Yankee",52000,
                2, 2019-01-26, 50010,50510,"METER","English",50000,

                3, 2017-03-07, 40750,41400,"MT","English",56900,
                3, 2018-05-26, 50010,50510,"MT","English",47000,
                3, 2019-01-21, 40750,40200,"MT","English",56000,
                3, 2019-01-21, 40750,40200,"MT","English",55900,

                4, 2017-11-08, 37500,39000,"LTR","Dynamic Sealbid",67000,
                4, 2017-11-08, 37500,39000,"LTR","Dynamic Sealbid",65900)

fit <- lm(WINNING_PRICE ~ Subcat, data = df)

plot(df$Subcat, y = df$WINNING_PRICE)
abline(fit)

#to fit many model to data with 'data' next column  
df2= df[,-2] %>% group_by(Subcat)%>%  nest()

df3 <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(fit = map(data, ~lm(WINNING_PRICE~COMM1, data = .)),
         results = map(fit, broom::augment))
#need to specify cols to unnest (this was changed recentlyish)
df4 <- df3 %>% unnest(cols = data)
```

Comment: So, in that case, using the following code can be helpful to include all the other variables? Do correct me if I am wrong. df3 <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(fit = map(data, ~lm(WINNING_PRICE~., data = .)),
         results = map(fit, broom::augment))  %>%  unnest(cols = data)

Comment: I used another way, df3=df2 %>% 
  as_tibble %>% 
  gather(key = "column", value = "value", c(3:37,39:44)) %>%       # first set the data in long format
  nest(WinningPrice, value) %>%                                     # now nest the dependent and independent factors
  mutate(model = map(data, ~lm(WinningPrice ~ value, data = .)))%>% # fit the model using purrr
  mutate(tidy_model = map(model, tidy))   %>%                           # clean the model output with broom
  select(-data, -model) %>%                                # remove the "untidy" parts
  unnest()

Answer (score 1):

I think something this should work:

```
model_fn <- function(df1){ 
  lm(WINNING_PRICE ~ AUC_TYPE, data = df1)
}

fitted_bestel <- df2 %>%
   mutate(fit = map(data, model_fn))
```

The error comes from the two dots you use (one as a substitute for all covariates and one for the data).